# Google + What's Hot list

Tags: api, google-plus

Is there a way to get the What's hot list using the api .

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search

I could not find any mention of this in the official documentation .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to get the what's hot list through the API.